# What mechanisms are available for firing Update triggers on Opportunity during a "Mass Transfer" action?

Tags: apex, trigger, workflow, ownership

In this case the "Mass Transfer" action being performed is clicking the *Change Owner* link on the parent Account record which subsequently bulk-reassigns the child Opportunity owners and does not execute the Opportunity [before | after] Update triggers nor does it execute a Workflow action on Opportunity.

I attempted to add a workflow rule to opportunity that runs on create and edit and increments a field, but alas it doesn't run during this particular operation.

How (else) can I cause these Update triggers to execute during this type of operation?

> **Relevant documentation:**
>
> Opportunity triggers are not fired when the account owner changes as a result of the associated opportunity's owner changing.
>
> When you modify an opportunity product on an opportunity, or when an opportunity product schedule changes an opportunity product, even if the opportunity product changes the opportunity, the before and after triggers and the validation rules don't fire for the opportunity. However, roll-up summary fields do get updated, and workflow rules associated with the opportunity do run.

*(Note: I am not modifying an Opportunity Product nor Schedule but would love for the workflow rules associated with the Opportunity to run...)*

[SFDC: Operations that Don't Invoke Triggers](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_triggers_ignoring_operations.htm)

Comment: Do any of your fields currently have formulas or look-ups that get updated by this action? If not, my thought was to see if adding a custom look-up field to the owner would cause a trigger to fire. Either that or creating a custom formula field that appends opp owner name to the opportunity name and running a validation rule on that.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully 1.5 years later your question has already been answered ;), but if not: I'd suggest creating a "dummy" field on the Opportunity object, using dataloader to download the Ids of the Opportunities that will need to be updated, in the spreadsheet it exports, add a dummy value (any string) to every record/row under that field's column in the sheet, then upload the spreadsheet to dataloader to update that value on all the records. When you're done, delete the field. Also - I'm referring to Dataloader.io (I use the free version, but it does have record limits), but I think you can do the same through the SF dataloader.